Darker image on rendering than viewport
my ocean modifier object is dark on high-resolution renders i.e. 1920x1080.
I covered the left side of the ocean with a plane with noise displacement to imitate a fake ocean for a seamless modifier-plane transition.
The render is fine on 50% of the resolution.
There's no issue of render and viewport object visibility restriction:
Viewport view:

Render View:


It looks like shadows are disabled in the viewport, but how to enable them might depend on the Blender version you are using as it is very old. Also, what render engine are you using? And, are you sure that the viewport is in render preview mode?

@TheLabCat but there's difference in resolution, if I render it in 2560x1440, it's dark, if I render in 50% of that resolution, it's fine

Uh, that’s weird. What version of Blender is this, and why is it so old?
